# Detecting Activity with mouse, keyboard and voice on windows

Tags: python, windows, win32com, pyaudio

We have a module on Python (through win32) to detect user mouse and keyboard activity by GetLastInputInfo and GetTickCount. How can we register Voice activity in GetLastInputInfo?

Or maybe can we add a synthesized input to update GetLastInputInfo every time the mic detects voice input? but can we do that without interrupting the user?

Sample code on Pyaudio to detect user voice by volume:

```
audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 2
RATE = 44100
CHUNK = 1024

# recording prerequisites
stream = audio.open(format=FORMAT, channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE,
                input=True,
                frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

while True:
   data = stream.read(CHUNK)
   data_chunk = array('h', data)
   vol = max(data_chunk)
   if vol >= 500:
      # voice detected from mic
      print("talking - {}".format(vol))
   else:
      print("-")
```

Sample code for detecting user input:

```
# code to get inactivity
class LastInputInfo(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("cbSize", UINT),
        ("dwTime", DWORD)
    ]


def _getLastInputTick() -> int:
    """
    retrieves the last input action
        :return: int
    """
    prototype = WINFUNCTYPE(BOOL, POINTER(LastInputInfo))
    paramflags = ((1, "lastinputinfo"), )
    # type: ignore
    c_GetLastInputInfo = prototype(("GetLastInputInfo", ctypes.windll.user32), paramflags)  

    l = LastInputInfo()
    l.cbSize = ctypes.sizeof(LastInputInfo)
    assert 0 != c_GetLastInputInfo(l)
    return l.dwTime


def _getTickCount() -> int:
    """
    :return: int
        tick count
    """
    prototype = WINFUNCTYPE(DWORD)
    paramflags = ()
    c_GetTickCount = prototype(("GetTickCount", ctypes.windll.kernel32), paramflags)  # type: ignore
    return c_GetTickCount()


def seconds_since_last_input():
    """
    :return: float
        the time of user input
    """
    seconds_since_input = (_getTickCount() - _getLastInputTick()) / 1000
    return seconds_since_input

# inactivity in N seconds
seconds_since_input = seconds_since_last_input()
inactive_seconds = 10
while True:
    # Becomes active
    if afk and seconds_since_input < inactive_seconds:
        afk = False

    #becomes afk
    elif not afk and seconds_since_input >= inactive_seconds:
        afk = True

    print("afk status: {}, seconds since last input :{}".format(seconds_since_input))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something, without interrupting the user, you can use **multithreading** with [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#module-threading).
If you want to save something in a variable that every thread can use, you can use [queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#module-queue).

This will run whatever you need to run, in a different thread, and save on a shared variable.

1. import modules

```py
import threading
import queue
```

2. Create a shared variable

```py
shared_var = queue.Queue()
```

3. Create a function that checks what you want (in this case audio), and edits the shared variable

Edit shared variable: `shared_var.put(item)`
(in this case, whenever audio is detected you can say `audio_detected.put(True)` and/or `current_tick_count.put(tick_count)`, or something like that`)

4. create a thread and pass in the function you made to check

```py
thread = threading.Thread(target=function, args=arguments)
```

where `target` is the function you want to call in this new tread, and `args` are the arguments you need to pass into your function

5. Start the new thread

```py
thread.start()
```

6. On main thread or a new thread, do what you want with that variable
   `shared_var.get()` will wait until something is added to `shared_var` and then return what was added.

Example code:

```py
import threading
import queue
import time

text = queue.Queue()

def change(text):
    time.sleep(3)
    text.put("hello world")



thread = threading.Thread(target=change, args=(text,))
#                                                  ^ IMPORTANT! (,)
thread.start()


def display(text):
    text = text.get() # This will wait till text has somthing inside and then returns it
    print(text)


thread2 = threading.Thread(target=display, args=(text,))
#                                                    ^ IMPORTANT! (,)
thread2.start()

input() # To show it won't interrupt the user until the text has something
```

**I am sorry if this answer isn't so clear. I'm not familiar with pyaudio and win32, but I do know [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#module-threading) and [queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#module-queue) so you can just work with this and add you're code. If you want you could edit the answer with your code in it.**

**I hope this helps!**

Comment: Hmm im curious, will the GetLastInputInfo updated with this?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand.

Comment: Hello, my initial concern is to update user input. I had a code that checks win32's "GetLastInputInfo" and then compare it with win32. "tickcount" so I can detect if the user is afk or not. If this threading has no effect with user input, I think this will not help me.

Comment: I can probably make you a program, that checks/runs something, and changes a variable, that the main thread can also see. So you can check/run something and return a result, without interrupting the user. Would that help? (if it would, I'll work on that and edit my answer)

Comment: Hmmm I dont know, my focus is with user input and output (keyboard input, and output) so i cant really say if threads can help me with this.

Comment: Did you try to "GetLastInputInfo" with a new thread? I'm not so familiar with "GetLastInputInfo", etc. but when I saw you wanted to do something without interrupting the user, I thought threading could help. Try to make a function (`def` ...) that does what your program does, and run it in a new thread. If that works I'll edit my answer to let it return, so you will know from the main thread. Sorry if I don't understand your question, I'm trying my best to answer.

Comment: You don't need GetLastInputInfo to be in a thread but you do need the pyaudio to be in a thread.  When the audio reaches the threshold level record the current tick count in a shared variable.  Create a custom local GetLastInputInfoAll function which compares the tick count delta of the audio as well as the Win32 GetLastInputInfo.